# How to return back object position in hinge joint

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm just new to unity2d, so I have a gameObject that has an hinge joint attached to another gameObject with rigidbody, Im trying to make a Wooden board that will behave like a "seesaw" and return back to its current position when the character is not set foot on it. How can I make it behave like a seesaw thanks!

This is the Original position of the gameObject where the other end of the wood is inclined down.

[image]

This should what must happen when my character puts weigh on the opposite end help please.

[image]

Comment: what about making it a fixed animation reacting on a "normal" trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I recommend in this case to use the "Motor" behaviour of joints:**
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HingeJoint-motor.html

So if you set to the "motor" of the joint a little bit of force, it will come back to the start position.

One more recomendation, depending of the force, the joint can "bounce" so I suggest to make some script that sets the motor force only when has interacted with the player, or stop doing the force if it's already on the start position, it's up to you! :D